# Linking error when adding IOS widget in flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, widget

I have a flutter app that I wanted to add widgets to so I followed this tutorial https://itnext.io/develop-an-ios-14-widget-in-flutter-with-swiftui-e98eaff2c606. Problem is that when I got to the part where I have to add an extra widget extension target to my app and try to run the app again using Xcode I get the below errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_analytics(FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_auth(FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseCorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_crashlytics(FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_messaging(FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.o)
      -[PermissionHandlerPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in permission_handler_apple(PermissionHandlerPlugin.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterEventChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_auth(FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.o)
  "_FlutterEndOfEventStream", referenced from:
      ___63-[FLTTransactionStreamHandler onListenWithArguments:eventSink:]_block_invoke.334 in cloud_firestore(FLTTransactionStreamHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTFirebaseFirestoreReaderWriter in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTFirebaseFirestoreReaderWriter in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTQuerySnapshotStreamHandler.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in permission_handler_apple(PermissionHandlerPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_analytics(FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_auth(FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_crashlytics(FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_messaging(FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in permission_handler_apple(PermissionHandlerPlugin.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardMethodCodec", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Flutter'
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter
 Undefined symbol: _FlutterMethodNotImplemented
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterEventChannel
 Undefined symbol: _FlutterEndOfEventStream
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel
 Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardMethodCodec
```

Comment: I am not a flutter developer but if I had to guess you likely have an M1 and however firebase is built it isn’t compiled for M1. It happens often with cocoa pods.

Comment: change directory to ```ios``` and try this command ```arch -x86_64 pod install```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the following settings to none:

[image]